# Google App Engine shuts down the instance and returns 500 errors

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

For no reason known GAE just shut down the instance.
There's the log showing 3 events:

```
Handling signal: term
Worker existing
Shutting down: Master
```

I've tried to stop and start a version in GAE but I get an error:

> Flex operation
>   projects/center/regions/europe-west1/operations/7f6-4f6e-a95e-4cad0e9d7307
>   error [INTERNAL]: An internal error occurred while processing task
>   /appengine-flex-v1/delete_flex_deployment/flex_delete_resources>2019-03-21T04:06:22.362Z12155.jc.3:
>   Deployment Manager operation
>   center/operation-1553141182646-58492dc7a4a74-abbc5c2d-282b2316 errors:
>   [code: "RESOURCE_ERROR" location:
>   "/deployments/aef-default-20181116t191408/resources/aef-default-20181116t191408-hcfw"
>   message:
>   "{\"ResourceType\":\"compute.v1.firewall\",\"ResourceErrorCode\":\"400\",\"ResourceErrorMessage\":{\"code\":400,\"errors\":[{\"domain\":\"global\",\"message\":\"The
>   resource \'projects/center/global/networks/default\' is not
>   ready\",\"reason\":\"resourceNotReady\"}],\"message\":\"The resource
>   \'projects/center/global/networks/default\' is not
>   ready\",\"statusMessage\":\"Bad
>   Request\",\"requestPath\":\"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/center/global/firewalls/aef-default-20181116t191408-hcfw\",\"httpMethod\":\"DELETE\"}}"
>   ]

I don't have much experience with GAE, so kind of lost what should I be doing next. Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: I can not see the 500 errors, but this may be an issue on our side. To debug it further you should open a case with Cloud Support (if you have the support package) or a Public Issue Tracker, as we may need to access the instance logs. [https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers].

Comment: Another thing you could try is to check if the Service Account that was created automatically by GAE was deleted. [https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/service-account]

Comment: Well the 500 errors are returned when I access the service from the browser.

Comment: That link you posted @NahuelVarela is not found.

Comment: And what's the account name that is created automatically by GAE? I can see some accounts. For example, there's one App Engine app default service account. I guess that's it @NahuelVarela

Comment: I'm sorry, both links have an extra ']'. Please, use the following link: 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491299&template=1161102 / This will create a private issue that only you and Googlers will have access to.

Also, the GAE service account link is:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/service-account